# How to transfer dynamic auth value in all requests instead of changing the value in every request's header in SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I am new in SOAP UI. I have an one scenario like I have to pass the access token value coming as a response to all the requests under the test suite.This access token type is "Bearer". I ADD this token value in the next request header field called "Authorization" and it is working but my query is there any method OR groovy script that I can add which can be applied for all the soap requests, instead of changing the value every time for all request's header.How to automate this?Please guide me on this.

Comment: Consider using transferring properties, the documentation is very clear with an example that is what you are trying to achieve, use this links as further reference http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html

Comment: Do you want to add an http-header with name `Authoritzation` and your token as value for the rest of the testSteps in this testSuite?

Comment: Hi Koitoer, Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes albciff. I want to make it automate the parameter so that If I made changes in one place it will give an impact for all the test steps related with this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, I suppose that you want to add an http-header for `Authoritzation` with your token as value for each request within this `testCase`, to do so you can put a `groovy script` testStep below the testStep request where you get your token. In this groovy script you can put the follow code which sets an http-header for each testStep in this testCase:

```
// testSteps is a map where keys are request names and values are the instance
// of the testStep
testRunner.testCase.testSteps.each{ name, testStep ->
    log.info name
    // check if the testStep has required methods (to avoid error
    // trying to add header on groovy script testSteps for example)
    if(testStep.metaClass.getMetaMethod("getTestRequest")){
        def request = testStep.getTestRequest()
        def headers = request.getRequestHeaders()
        headers.add('Authoritzation','yourToken')
        request.setRequestHeaders(headers)
        log.info "Added header to $name"
    }
}
```

This script adds the required http-header for each testStep in your testCase.

**EDIT**

Another possible approach is to add a testCase property as an http-header value and then set the value for this property when you need to refresh this value. To do so in your TestStep request click on `Headers()` tab and add a http-header with name `Authoritzation` and value `${#TestCase#Authoritzation}` as in the follow image:

[image]

Then each time that you want to set the value for this property you can use different approaches (I don't have enough details about your case so I give you different possible solutions), property transfer testStep or a groovy script testStep using `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('Authoritzation',yourToken)`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you albciff. Let me check whether it's working fine for me or not.Looking forward I may need your guidance for setting up this value.Is there any other way to resolve this? @albciff

Comment: @chittabratabanerjee excuse me but I don't understand your comment, what did you mean with "setting up this value"?

Comment: Hi albciff, actually this  generated Access_token is not passing in request body for next req. All they are POSt request. So I have to pass this value in req header for the next request.So I add your code to that test step where access token @generated.headers.add('Auth','acess_token').Now i add this value in next req header like this : authorization = bearer ${Auth}.But it is not working.

Comment: @chittabratabanerjee the thing is that you want to add the auth token as `http-header` however you change this value on different request and you don't want to execute this script each time, isn't it?

Comment: yes  this is correct.This auth token added in http-header but this will not change on diff req level every time. This token value will expired after 24 hours before that it is same for all the requests. So I want this value automatically pass into diff request level in http header only instead of changing it manually at all the level.