# Passing token from get request to a header in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a `getToken` request in a test case `get_Admin_Token` in `PassToken` test suite, where I have as a response following JSON:

```
{
   "access_token": "5701f536-0bd5-441f-a490-21aafeasdasdd",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "c53af657-8292-4aff-xxxx-xxxf0ffed310",
   "expires_in": 80208,
   "scope": "read write trust"
}
```

I need to use `access_token` value in `uploadFile` method, but I need to pass it in a header. I have a field `Authorization` with `Bearer: $(access_token)` value.

Using some google I found:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-do-I-do-a-property-transfer-with-multiple-source-responses/td-p/106456 question, which was looking similar. I started to create a GroovyScript test step, where I used code to pass it to the Properties table, but no success. I was also trying to put it to assertions for the `get_Admin_Token`, but I got a message about incorrect object types. I also tried to use `def accessToken = jsonSlurper.access_token.toString()` to use strings, but now I got an error `

```
No signature of method: 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.setProperty() is 
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: 
[AUTH_KEY, Bearer 5701f536-0bd5-441f-a490-21aafeasdasdd] Possible solutions: 
getProperty(java.lang.String), addProperty(java.lang.String), 
hasProperty(java.lang.String), hasProperty(java.lang.String), getProject(), 
getProperties()
```

My groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())
def accessToken = jsonSlurper.access_token.toString()
assert null != accessToken, "access_token does not have a value"
def authorizationKey = "${accessToken}"
context.testCase.setProperty('AUTH_KEY',"Bearer " + authorizationKey)
```

Is this code valid? I'm not sure what to put in next method as authorization value in header, I tried with `${#get_Admin_Token#AUTH_KEY}`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Easier way**
Just pass Token to properties using transfer action and set in header `Bearer ${Properties#AdminToken}`. That's all

===================

**Old version**:

The following answer is correct if anyone is looking for the Groovy script:

Ok, I think I spotted a workaround.
Groovy code is as following:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())
def accessToken = jsonSlurper.access_token.toString()
assert null != accessToken, "access_token does not have a value"
def authorizationKey = "${accessToken}"
context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("AUTH_KEY","Bearer " + authorizationKey)
log.info context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "AUTH_KEY" )
```

And using answer presented here: [How to transfer dynamic auth value in all requests instead of changing the value in every request's header in SOAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008555/how-to-transfer-dynamic-auth-value-in-all-requests-instead-of-changing-the-value?rq=1) I created a new GroovyScript Test Case:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps.each{ name, testStep ->
    log.info name
    if(testStep.metaClass.getMetaMethod("getTestRequest")){
        if(name=="UploadScreenshot"){
        def request = testStep.getTestRequest()
        def headers = request.getRequestHeaders()
        headers.add('Authoritzation',context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "AUTH_KEY" ))
        request.setRequestHeaders(headers)
        log.info "Added header to $name"
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's not a very good idea, to put an `if` to the loop instead if delete a loop, but I don't know yet how to do it and I need to proceed with work